# "Authorize" works alone but not with Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The application I'm building needs several roles and initially seems to work fine: I can login with "User1" and upon debutting, "IsRole_ModuleAll_Admin" returns true :

```
    IdentityUser MyUser = UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefault();
    IList<string> MyRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(MyUser);


    bool IsRole_ModuleAll_Admin = MyRoles.Contains("Module: All - Admin"); //True
    bool IsRole_ModuleStatus_TechnicianOSC = MyRoles.Contains("Module: Status - TechnicianOSC");
    bool IsRole_ModuleStatus_Admin = MyRoles.Contains("Module: Status - Admin");

    if (IsRole_ModuleAll_Admin || IsRole_ModuleStatus_TechnicianOSC)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="#StatusSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="PlannerSubmenu"><i class="fas fa-satellite-dish fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Status</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="StatusSubmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href=@Url.Action("Last_GGG", "Status")><i class="fas fa-industry fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;GGG</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href=@Url.Action("Last_ASU", "Status")><i class="fas fa-city fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ASU</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
```

Now, inside Status/Last_GGG the following code works... but when I uncomment [Authorize(Roles...)] and comment out [Authorize] I get an identity error "Access denied - You don't have access to this resource". Any idea why is this happening?

```
namespace Viewer.Controllers._03_ModuleStatus
{
    [Authorize]
    //[Authorize(Roles = "Module: All - Admin, Module: Status - TechnicianOSC, Module: Status - Admin")]
    public class StatusController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IGGGRepository _GGGRepository;
        public IEnumerable<GGG> ListOfAllGGG;

        public StatusController(IGGGRepository GGGRepository)
        {
            _GGGRepository = GGGRepository;
        }

        public IActionResult Last_GGG()
        {
            GGGPlannerViewModel GGGViewModel = new GGGPlannerViewModel();
            GGGViewModel.GGGList = _GGGRepository.GGGs;
            GGGViewModel.CurrentValues = _GGGRepository.CurrentValuesinDB;
            return View(GGGViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value for `MyRoles`? Does `IsRole_ModuleAll_Admin`, `IsRole_ModuleStatus_TechnicianOSC` and `IsRole_ModuleStatus_Admin` all return true?

Comment: That user has only "Module: All - Admin" assigned, so only that is returning true.

Comment: For `Authorize` with role, all the values in the roles parameter should be assigned to user. You need to implement your own Authorize attribute.

Comment: Hi Tao, I think it's the contrary: This following case lets users "members" OR "admin" to go: [Authorize(Roles="members, admin")]. However, this following case lets users "members" AND "admin" to go: [Authorize(Roles="members")][Authorize(Roles="admin")]